# socket.on is not listening for a event

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am creating a simple private and group chat app using react.js, node.js and socket.io. I have **emitted an event on form submit**. And on server and client side, I listened for that event.

It's working on server side fine, But on client side it's not listening for the event. Below is my client side and server side code:

server:

```
var users = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
    socket.on('user_email', (data) => {
        console.log('user_email event called!');
        users[data.email] = socket.id;
    });
    socket.on('sent_message',(data)=>{
        console.log('data is ',data);
    })
});
```

client:

```
import socket from '../../socket';

handleSubmit(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     let email = window.localStorage.getItem('email');      
     let message = this.state.message;
     if(message){
        socket.emit('sent_message',{email:email,message:message});
    }
    socket.on('sent_message',(data)=>{
        console.log('client side',data);
    })
}
```

socket.js

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import { CONFIG } from './config';

export default socketIOClient(CONFIG.API_BASE_URL);
```

Comment: in the config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your client code you have:

```
socket.emit('sent_message',{email:email,message:message});

// and

socket.on('sent_message',(data)=>{
    console.log('client side',data);
})
```

And on server you have

```
socket.on('sent_message',(data)=>{
    console.log('data is ',data);
})
```

But on your server, there is no `...emit('sent_message', ...)` so your client will never receive anything.

Try using

```
io.to(socket.id).emit('sent_message', data);
```

inside your server code, inside the `socket.on('sent_message', ...)` handler, instead of the `console.log('data is ', data);`

Comment: can i use socket.emit inside socket.on?

Comment: use `io.to(socket.id).emit()` to send the emission to that socket in particular.  You can use `.broadcast()` instead if you want all connected clients to receive but for now, try this to troubleshoot the issue.  Also, yes to answer your question - you should be able to do that as well.  https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack

Comment: I am implementing group chat, so don't i need to use io.to(socket.id).emit?

Comment: If you are doing a group chat you'll want to use namespaces or rooms to isolate who gets the messages. It will still broadcast but only to people subscribed to like `/group1`, etc - see this for that https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-rooms

Comment: thank you so much brother. If i need your help in future, can you help me?

Comment: sorry bro, I can't pay

Comment: ah well if i see more questions here ill do what i can :)

Comment: thank you so much. socket.broadcast.emit('') is not emitting event to all clients.

Comment: yeah like i mentioned at the end of that other message, you can still use `socket.emit('message', ...)` inside of a `socket.on(...)` ive just been using it in a very specific way lately so my bias got in the way.  For instance:  `socket.on('echo', function ( data ) {  socket.emit('success', { hello: 'world' });  });`

Comment: but socket.emit("") not broacasting message to all connected clients.

Comment: please have a look at my server side code:

https://pastebin.com/QgWS5fqS

Comment: try replacing `socket.broadcast.emit('sent_message',data);` with `socket.emit('sent_message',data);`.  those docs should be a pretty good resource for you here tho

Comment: I added socket.broadcast.emit and socket.emit both, and now it's working fine